# CDbCriteria addConditions where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to filter the records by date, so I have added

```
createDate BETWEEN ' . $dateRange['start'] . ' AND ' . $dateRange['end']
```

To my criteria but I get:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'createDate' in where clause is ambiguous
```

This is my code :

```
     $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->with = array(
                        'Contacts' => array('alias'=> 'Contacts', 'together' => true, ),
                        'Lisings' => array('alias'=> 'listings', 'together' => true, ),
                    );
     $criteria->addCondition('createDate BETWEEN ' . $dateRange['start'] . ' AND ' . $dateRange['end']);

     $result = Model::model('Portfolio')->findAll($criteria);
```

Any tips to fix this error? I have tried `portfolio.createDate` as well, but it's not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii 1, the model table was aliased to `t` so you should use:

```
$criteria->addCondition('t.createDate BETWEEN ' . $dateRange['start'] . ' AND ' . $dateRange['end']);
```